# MATLAB Get a list of color map names

Tags: matlab, user-interface, colormap

I am writing a GUI that would benefit from a user-selection of colormaps by name. However, I am at a bit of a quandary in that I can't seem to programmatically get a list of supported colormap names!

While I could hardcode the names; my code may be run on older versions of matlab which may have different colormaps. My primary concern is with the *parula* colormap which, if I recall correctly, was not present in MATLAB 2014.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Indeed. Parula was presented in MATLAB 2014b but not in 2014a

Comment: Hey! people gave you some cool answers, consider accepting one of them as valid

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alternatively, you can hardcode them and have an `if` statement with `graphicsversion(fhandle)` on it.

> It returns  returns true if the default graphics system is the old
>   handle graphics one.

---

You could also try to get an extensive list, and then check if `colormapname.m` is a file in `matlabroot\toolbox\matlab\graph3d`. If the function is there, the colormap comes in that version. You'd still need to hardcode an extensive list though.

**EDIT:** as @thewaywewalk suggests, you could open `Contents.m`in `matlabroot\toolbox\matlab\graph3d` and esarch for `% Color maps.` It has a list of the colormaps included in the version. In 2014b its on lines 29-48

Comment: To avoid the hardcoding you could open the `matlabroot\toolbox\matlab\graph3d\contents.m` and get the list by string processing of the file.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Brilliant! I have added that to the answer!

Comment: @thewaywewalk It does not appear that my matlab 2015a has this contents.m file in that directory.

Comment: @warpstack its `Contents.m` with a capital letter, just in case.

Answer (score 4):

<s>I'm not 100% sure it works in MATLAB</s> As @BillBokeey points out in the comments this does not work in MATLAB, but in Octave you can use:

```
CM = colormap('list');
```

It will return a cell array of strings containing all of the valid colormaps.

```
CM =
{
  [1,1] = autumn
  [1,2] = bone
  [1,3] = cool
  [1,4] = copper
  [1,5] = flag
  [1,6] = gmap40
  [1,7] = gray
  [1,8] = hot
  [1,9] = hsv
  [1,10] = jet
  [1,11] = lines
  [1,12] = ocean
  [1,13] = pink
  [1,14] = prism
  [1,15] = rainbow
  [1,16] = spring
  [1,17] = summer
  [1,18] = white
  [1,19] = winter
}
```

Comment: @BillBokeey Drat. Thanks for checking.

Comment: I'm tempted to DV+comment "Not the right language" :D

Comment: @Adriaan If people would stop upvoting it, I'd delete it. As it stands, maybe it should become a feature request.

Answer (score 4):

A possibility to get an extensive list of available colormaps :

In `matlabroot\help\matlab\ref`, you can find previews of all available colormaps whose filenames are of the form `colormap_colormapname.png`

In order to get your list, you can use :

```
CurrFolder=pwd;

cd(strcat(matlabroot,'\help\matlab\ref'))

Colormaps=dir('*colormap_*.png');

TmpColormapsList={Colormaps.name};

TmpColormapsList=cellfun(@(S)strrep(S,'colormap_',''),TmpColormapsList,'UniformOutput',false);

ColormapsList=cellfun(@(S)strrep(S,'.png',''),TmpColormapsList,'UniformOutput',false);

cd(CurrFolder);
```

This will output a cell array of string containing the names of the available colormaps.

Pretty ugly hack, but at least it works on 2014b (Please check it for your version if you have another one)

Comment: Missing `vga` in 2014b

Answer (score 2):

Another way (hack) might be to extract the string out the the `colormapeditor` function:

```
colormapeditorString = fileread(strcat(matlabroot,'\toolbox\matlab\graph3d\colormapeditor.m'));
posStart = strfind(colormapeditorString,'stdcmap(maptype');
posEnd = strfind(colormapeditorString(posStart:end),'end') + posStart;
stdcmapString = colormapeditorString(posStart:posEnd);
split = strsplit(stdcmapString, '(mapsize)');
list = cellfun(@(x)x(find(x==' ', 1,'last'):end), split,'uni',0);
list(end) = [];
```

Comment: Missing `vga` on Windows and matlab 2014b

Comment: `vga` isn't really a regular colour map though, it behaves differently as it doesn't have the interpolation the other maps do so for example where you can go `parula(32)`, `vga(32)` is an error.

Comment: Yes, yes, you are right. I upvoted this answer and I believe is better than mine. I don't thing vga is useful for anythings, just pointing out that is missing, for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

If everything fails you can try the callback routine:

```
function=ChangeCMap()
  CMList=get(CMapList,'string');                            %% Read colormap names
  CMVal =get(CMapList,'value');                             %% Get the index of desired colormap

  try
    colormap(Ax,CMList{CMVal});                             %% Try to set the colormap...
  catch Msg                                                 %% ... if it fails, then:
    if strcmp(Msg.stack.name,'colormap')                    %% Check if error was caused by colormap function
      set(Ax,'colormap`,'jet');                             %% set "default" colormap (optional)
      indices=1:length(CMList);
      set(CMapList,'string',CMList{indices~=CMVal})         %% remove the colormap name thet caused error
    else
      disp(Msg)                                             %% Print the error message in matlab shell
    end
  end
end
```

In this example shared variables `CMapList` - handle to the popup menu - and `Ax` - handle of the axes - are expected.

When the function is called it tries to set the colormap. If it fails it set the default colormap and remove the problematic name from the menu.

Be sure that first and last colormaps won't cause error, otherwise the `CMapList` update will have to handle those options.

---

You can also benefit from the fact, that each colormap has its own `.m` file so you don't need to wait until error occurs.

```
CMap='bone';   %% example
if exist(CMap,'file')
  colormap(Ax,CMap)  %% bone.m exist somewhere in the matlab paths
else
  colormap(Ax,'jet') %% bone.m does not exist in the matlab paths
end
```

This raises one point - you can define your own colormaps and make the algorithm to generate missing `.m` files...

Comment: Good answer, but I believe the error checking shoudl be added to it.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I've tried to add error check and another approach.

Answer (score 1):

Given that any function that returns a 3-column matrix, or even a .MAT file containing a `cmap` variable with such a matrix, can be used by `colormap`, it doesn't make sense to ask for a list of “all” colormaps.

You might use `exist` (i.e., `exist('parula', 'file')`), or `try` clauses, to check for the existence of certain functions and offer them as colormaps in your GUI, though that might be problematic if the user has custom functions with the same name that don't yield colormaps.

I have users who love making totally custom colormaps, which they save in MAT files, so for them, I'd make the colormap a customizable textfield, and do some validation to ensure that it is indeed a valid colormap.

Comment: a list of all colormaps included by default in MATLAB, not a list of all possible colormaps, you are missing the point

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had the same issue building an app in app generator. After finding the above attempts overly cumbersome, I have decided to provide my approach.

Matlab stores it's colormaps as *.m files in a single directory, so select for the filenames in this directory.

```
coldir = dir([matlabroot '\toolbox\matlab\graphics\color']);
maps={};
for i=1:length(coldir)
    if coldir(i).isdir, continue, end
    maps{end+1}=replace(coldir(i).name,'.m','');
end
```

Comment: Since what version does MATLAB store them this way? Didn’t use to be this way.